# Android - Taking classes from my project and making that into a jar

Tags: android, jar

Alright so I have a android project and It is working fine. Now i want to take some of the classes in it and put it into a jar and then include that jar in my project. I'm not exactly sure how to do that. The files have R in it and not sure if they will affect anything. Im keeping the xml files in the original project, so basically all i want is the .java files be put into the jar and then referenced.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new project for your classes and mark it as `library`, in eclipse go to 
`Project properties -> Android` and then check `Is library`

To use your library in a new project, again go to 
`Project properties -> Android` and click `Add` button and select your library.

You might need to have both projects in the same workspace.

The resources files (i.e. `R`) defined in you library will be accessible in your new project, so you can use it as if it is defined in your new project.

Comment: Hey, thanks for a reply. What if I want to upload my code to github and don't want to upload the reference library code and instead want to upload a jar file? 
What you told me works but what I really want is a way to make that library into a jar. But for some reason when I export the new project with the classes into a jar, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate library project. If you are using the command line, create a directory for the project, cd to it, and use

```
android create lib-project
```

The help output will tell you the flags this command requires.

After you move the classes to the library project, cd back to your main project and type

```
android update project -p . -l <path-to-library-project>
```

Now when you compile your main project, it will also compile the library project, create a jar file, and import its classes into your main project. For more details about library projects, check out [Managing Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html). If you are using Eclipse, check out [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html).

Comment: @jhysum The command line I refer to here is the command line on your development computer.

Comment: Okay, nevermind I got up to using android create lib-project, but i need a target and when i do android list targets, its not showing anything up.
But i just made the library using eclipse so i guess it turned out fine.